# infrastructure-as-a-code tag is misspelled

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The tag [infrastructure-as-a-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/infrastructure-as-a-code) must be a misspelling or mixup. The correct term is [Infrastructure as Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_as_code) or IaC. But here it seems to be mixed up with the acronym IaaS, [Infrastructure as a Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_as_a_service). Both terms are cloud related.

As the tag is now [infrastructure-as-a-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/infrastructure-as-a-code) - there is no such thing.

Can we change [infrastructure-as-a-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/infrastructure-as-a-code) to the correct term [infrastructure-as-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/infrastructure-as-code)?

Comment: Sounds awesome to me.  Many infrastructures.  One code.  Hopefully, a short one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You make a reasonable point. Maybe someone got it confused with the [Institute for Advanced Architecture of Catalonia (IAAC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institute_for_Advanced_Architecture_of_Catalonia)? I don't know.

Either way, tag is now renamed and the wiki has been updated.